# Laravel select distinct value

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I have the following request

```
$latestTrailers =  DB::table('game_trailer')
                        ->join('trailers', 'trailers.id', '=', 'game_trailer.trailer_id')
                        ->join('games', 'games.id', '=', 'game_trailer.game_id')
                        ->join('device', 'device.id', '=', 'games.device_id')
                        ->where('game_trailer.bool', 1)
                        ->orderBy('game_trailer.created_at', 'desc')
                        ->select('name', 'trailer_link', 'device_url', 'game_trailer.created_at')
                        ->limit(3)
                        ->get();
```

And the following result

```
    Collection {#407 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#420 ▼
      +"name": "Persona 5"
      +"trailer_link": "cc-ClutaN_I"
      +"device_url": "ps4"
      +"created_at": "2018-02-13 16:32:34"
    }
    1 => {#395 ▼
      +"name": "Persona 5"
      +"trailer_link": "cc-ClutaN_I"
      +"device_url": "ps3"
      +"created_at": "2018-02-13 16:30:36"
    }
    2 => {#427 ▼
      +"name": "Halo 3: ODST"
      +"trailer_link": "Zz6FNKawJBc"
      +"device_url": "microsoft-xbox-360"
      +"created_at": "2018-02-13 16:27:56"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like the "trailer_link" value to be unique. And so make the request select the next entrie in the database if this column is not unique.

I tried the distinct() method but it doesn't work as I only want to use it on only one value.

Are there any equivalents ? Or another way to do it ?

Comment: try `groupBy('trailer_link')`

Comment: I tried this one and got the following error that I wasn't able to resolve either
`Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column `

Comment: seems strict db problem, you need to disable strict mode, in your config/database `'strict' => false,`

Comment: Thank you, that works for the `groupBy('trailer_link')`, but now the `orderBy` doesn't work, it only select the 3 first entries.

Comment: in your code you have , limit(3) , to only select the 3 first entries

Comment: My bad I just missread the data, the limit(3) is fine, everything works, thank everyone.